# Ограничить число итераций foreach

Tags: php, sqlite, foreach, limit

Подскажите, как **ограничить количество строк таблицы, выводимых циклом foreach** из БД sqlite на страницу? Нужно выводить не более 500 строк. а в БД их 10 тысяч.

Этот код выводит все строки по запросу:

```
<?php foreach(property_list('`rooms` LIKE "1(%"') as $item):?>
<tr>
        <td><?=$item['rooms']?></td>
        <td><?=$item['area']?></td>
        // еще десяток ячеек с данными из БД
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Пыталась сделать ограничение количества tr так:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach(property_list('`rooms` LIKE "1(%"') as $item):?>

    <tr> 
    <td><?=$item['rooms']?></td>
    <td><?=$item['area']?></td>
    <td>...</td> 
    </tr>
    $i+=1;
    if (++i > 500) break;
<?php endforeach;?> 
?>
```

Но в результате на страницу ровно 500 раз выводятся не данные из БД, а:

> $i+=1; if (++i > 500) break;

Подскажите, что неправильно сделала? Мне пока ума не хватает до конца довести.

Спасибо!

P.S.

```
function property_list($where=FALSE){
    $db = db();
    //return $db->query("SELECT * FROM property ".($where?'WHERE '.$where:'').' ORDER BY `rooms`',PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $db->query("SELECT * FROM property ".($where?'WHERE '.$where:'').' ORDER BY `created_at` DESC',PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

> Цитата

Comment: что такое property_list()? все ограничения должны происходить там _внутри_

Comment: А! То есть я туда должна дописать что-то вроде LIMIT?

Comment: совершенно верно

Comment: Получайте данные до цикла!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Можешь лимит в запросе поставить

```
    function property_list($where=FALSE){
        $db = db();
        return $db->query("SELECT * FROM property ".($where?'WHERE '.$where:'').' ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 500',PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

2. Или свое условие поместить в php тег

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach(property_list('`rooms` LIKE "1(%"') as $item):?>

    <tr> 
    <td><?=$item['rooms']?></td>
    <td><?=$item['area']?></td>
    <td>...</td> 
    </tr>
<?php 
    $i++;
    if (i > 500) break; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Установила лимит в запросе (в функции property_list). И все получилось.  Второй вариант тоже интересен с точки зрения "знать и уметь".